# JS classList.add not applying to Element when I inspect it, however it shows the class has been added successfully in console

Tags: javascript, html

So this is a bit of a silly problem. I am doing some hacky stuff on a Wordpress website for a client that has an unfortunate setup of their website.

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.getElementById('js-mobile-menu-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    setTimeout(function(){

      var mobileParentMenuItem;
      mobileParentMenuItem = document.querySelector('.js-mobile-menu-item a');
      console.log(mobileParentMenuItem);
      mobileParentMenuItem.classList.add('active-mobile-menu-item');
      console.log(mobileParentMenuItem.classList);

    }, 500);

  }, false);

}, false);
```

I have no errors in console and both console logs display correctly, here you can see:

[image]

So it finds the element no problem and as I display the classlist it shows that the element does indeed have this class I added, however when I inspect the element the class is not there and the styling is not applying:

[image]

I have a feeling that the issue here is the setTimeout, however I need it there because it takes a second for the mobile menu to display after clicking on the hamburger, so if I do not have the setTimeout there then it cant find the mobileParentMenuItem. Perhaps there is a better way to do this without the setTimeout?

I am not sure how to fix this problem, would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Maybe the mobile-menu code is clearing active-mobile-menu-item as part of displaying the menu?

Comment: It definitely could be that - they are using Elementor on their WP site so perhaps it is clearing my custom class? I have managed to successfully add in custom classes in this way before (on the same site), the only difference is the setTimeout. So I am really not sure.

Comment: You can set an attribute breakpoint on the element and detect when it changes. Then you'll see what code is doing it.